# Using a "base" repository for a project?

Tags: javascript, git, github

Good morning all!

I'm hoping you all may have some experience that can guide me in the correct direction.  Apologies if I do a poor job of explaining this.

I have a Git repo that I use as a shell for dashboards I create (will call it ShellRepo).  What I had been doing is cloning this repo (will call it DashboardRepo) and then building out a dashboard each time I have a new project.  The problem is that if I find a change to make to the ShellRepo, I'm not sure how to update DashboardRepo to take in the new changes while also preserving the new files and customizations I added specific to the DashboardRepo project.

I looked into submodules, but I'm not sure this will work (or maybe I am misunderstanding them) because the changes I make are within the directory provided by the ShellRepo.  I want to add files to my DashboardRepo to make specific customizations, but allow for updating of the core files from ShellRepo if I find and implement a more general change.

Is there any suggested method of tackling this issue?  Thank you all for your time!

Comment: A friend of mine suggested a fork.  Each DashboardRepo I create could be a fork of the ShellRepo, and then I could pull in the ShellRepo to each fork as when updated.  Since I'm being careful not to overwrite files in the DashboardRepos I create, there should be no merge conflicts.  Will update after I can test it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep two different remotes urls, one for your ShellRepo and a second for your DashboardRepo, and move changes from DashboardRepo to ShellRepo.

For example, let's supposed that:

- You are already in DashboardRepo on `master` branch.
- You created a commit with a hash `a1b2c3` with some general changes that you want to apply to ShellRepo specifically on its `master` branch.

I would follow these steps:

1. Add ShellRepo remote to your local repository: `git remote add shell
   <your remote url>`
2. Switch to the branch you want to apply your change to: `git checkout remotes/shell/master`.
3. At this moment you will be in detached mode so let's create a local branch with `git checkout -b shell-master`.
4. Now let's apply the change: `git cherry-pick a1b2c3`
5. Finally you can push this change to your ShellRepo using: `git push -u shell master`.

Then any time you want to move a change you can switch to `shell-master` and cherry-pick the commits containing thoses changes.